# How to integrate mobile application (restaurant menu) with micros pos developed using flash builder 4.6 and actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, point-of-sale

I have developed  a **restaurant menu app for samsung galaxy tab 8.9** .I want to send all ordered details to micros pos eg item name,table name qty ordered , item price to pos .I have deeveloped this application using flash builder 4.6 ie used flex 4.6 and actionscript as technologies .So **how do i integrate my application with micros pos to send all data ordered to it with micros pos**??

Answer (score 0):

Easy : you need a server and an application on that server , did you develop it too ? then it should not be hard to send your datas via http/https back to your server from your app.
Your flash app is only a client app , like the app on the samsung , they are clients , you need a server app.

Comment: Thank @camus for the reply. is this the api http://serverapi:api port/api data/application name/modifier list.camus can  you just give any link which will be very useful for me to develop server app to pass all ordered data.

Comment: depends on what kind off technology you are using on the server .php , java , .net ? then you need to choose a protocol , xml-rpc ? amf ? soap ? rest ?

Comment: Thanks once again camus will use either php or java and xml-rpc. please any link or tutorila which will guide me for the developement of the server app .please help

Answer (score 0):

[MICROS](http://www.micros.com/ServicesAndSupport/ProductIntegration/RestaurantIntegration/MicrosPosIntegration.aspx) will allow you to integrate, but you generally have to pay the price of admission.  They even tell you on their site that it starts at $15,000.  This fee, like everything in business, is based on your benefit to them and is negotiable based on what you bring to the table.